# Why is conda not installing a dist-info for my main installation target, but is for all its dependencies?

Tags: python, conda, metadata, conda-build

I'm building/installing a package: `foo`, using `conda`, which has several dependencies: `bar` and `blatz`, which I'm also building/installing with `conda`.
They all build without error.
When I `conda install foo`, `foo` and all its dependencies get installed correctly and I can run `foo` just fine.
But, while all `foo`'s dependencies get equivalent `...dist-info` folders installed into `site-packages/`, `foo` does not!
And that makes it impossible to use the following trick for automatic version reporting:

(`foo/__init__.py`):

```py
from importlib.metadata import version
__version__ = version('foo')
```

**Why does `conda` omit the `...dist-info` folder for the main installation target, while including it for the dependencies?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this was a false alarm caused by slightly different package names used on the `conda` (PyBERT) and `pip` (PipBERT) sides of the fence. :(

**==> You must use the *Pip* package name in the code shown above.**